# How shall I specify the URL to a page in a book in Google Books?

Tags: google-books

In URL https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PA126&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false, what do the following query strings mean:

- "lpg=PA126"
- "pg=PA126#v=onepage"
- "q"
- "f=false"?

If I want to specify the URL to a particular page in a book, shall I modify the value of "lpg" or the one of "pg"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the given example, the URL is: `https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PA126&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false`

The URL could also be written as: `https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA126#v=onepage&f=false`

**The URL syntax is**:

- `id`: The book ID (`id=rAy-NliGEPMC`)
- `pg`: The page number (`pg=PA126`)
- `lpg`: The landing page (`lpg=PA126`) – see below for more info
- `v`: Whether viewed as a centerfold or a single page (`v=onepage` OR `v=twopage`)
- `f`: Whether to hide the left hand side-bar or not (`f=false` OR `f=true`)

---

Although not officially documented, **the `lpg=` parameter refers to the landing page to the Google Book**.

How this works in our example:

- When you first land (through a link) to page 126, the link is: `https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false`
- When you want to share the link by clicking the button with the chain-link icon while on the same page, the copied link changes to: `https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PA126&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false`

  [image: copied Google Books page URL same as landing page]

  (It adds the parameter `&lpg=PA126` before `&pg=PA126`.)
- If you then go to page 137 (for example) and then try to share the link, the new copied link becomes: `https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PA126&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q&f=false`

  [image: copied Google Books page URL other than landing page]

  (It changes `&pg=PA126` to `&pg=PA137`, but the `&lpg=PA126` parameter is unchanged.)

Comment: Web services are by definition stateless. I guess with lpg Google Books becomes stateful

Comment: Well... That's Google for you :/